# shell script to run commands after sudo su - appuser

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel, git

My organization gives me no access to root and has some very weird authentication that is explained below:

- I login to the RHEL server using my username and password combination via ssh terminal
- I am not allowed to use my account and must switch to the server account using the following command: `sudo su - appuser`
- any permutation to the command above is not allowed. Meaning `sudo su -p appuser` is not allowed `sudo su appuser` is not allowed. IT MUST BE `sudo su - appuser`. I get to enter my password before I switch to appuser
- now I am in the appuser which does not have sudo rights.. I do my work now.

recently I started using git and in git you can specify username and password. Well, if my team of 6 people use it, they will all have the same username.
unless they run the following command line to get their real username after they switch to the appuser: `git config --global user.name $(logname)`

So, I am trying to navigate this poor infrastructure that I do not have control over by making a script that will allow me to switch user and set my git user immediately after I switch to the appuser.

What I currently have is this (which does not work because I get asked for the password because of line 1):

```
sudo su - appuser
git config --global user.email $(logname)
```

What are my options other than going to IT and asking for a solution that I know they will not provide?

Comment: Do the 6 people in your team all work in the same directory when they are using git or do they have their own? Is it possible that 2 or more people from your team might be logged in as `appuser` on the server at the same time?

Comment: You can solve your problem on line 1 with `expect`, but that might be problematic (security wise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set environment variables based on your logname:

```
case $logname in
shnisaka)
  export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="your name"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="your name"
  export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="your.name@compa.ny"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="your.name@compa.ny"
  ;;
olqs)
  export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="my name"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="my name"
  export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="my.name@compa.ny"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="my.name@compa.ny"
  ;;
esac
```

We have a similar config in our profile settings. Try to put it in the .bashrc of appuser

Comment: What do you have to put in your ~/.gitconfig file to make those variables read by git?

Comment: You normally don't have to put anything in your ~/.gitconfig. Environment variables are a normal feature of the git client: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables